# ajax request not  sent in IE6

Tags: django, internet-explorer, jquery

I am developing a webpage with all actions handled as ajax.It works fine in firefox,IE 8,7.But in IE 6 no request is being sent to the sever.Why does this happen.I amusing jquery.getjson and jquery.colourbox methods to fetch data and display in colorbox.

```
 <a href="/account/change-pass/" class="t_2 cboxElement changepass">Change Password<span class=""></span></a> $('a.changepass').colorbox();
```

This is the html code and i need to open the contents of returned response in colorbox.This works fine with IE 7,8 and firefox.

Comment: Is your URL of the webpage and URL where you are making the call same? It might fail because it might not follow same domain policy. Also are there any special characters in the request?

Comment: no there is'nt any special characters and request is sent to same domain only

Comment: Please enlighten us with your code.

Comment: Why are you trying to get something to work for a dead browser? :/

Comment: my website has 20% traffic from IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, this maybe a **cache problem**.
IE try caching everything requested from a url.

if u request the same url for 2nd time, ie will return the old data by 1st request without any network.

to solv ie's url cache, adding a "?" or current timestamp param to request url.

```
http://abc.com/ajax?t=123455
```

Comment: first request itself is not being sent

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this about the UTF-8?
http://firelitdesign.blogspot.com/2009/07/jquerys-getjson.html

Comment: In my case the request itself is not being sent....the above link deals with encoding of the response.